# prevent automatic sorting when inserting with fn split

Tags: sql, t-sql

Inserts properly, however sorts id while inserting

If I execute the stored procedure parameters username = dynamic and id = 19,1,10
then when i check the Favorites table i see:

[image]

```
INSERT INTO Favorites(username, id) 
SELECT  @username, i.item
FROM fnSplit(@id, ',') i
INNER JOIN dbo.Link f on f.id = i.item
WHERE id IS NOT NULL
```

More information about split function:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt684588.aspx
NOTE: I am using a different name for the function but it is the same thing

Comment: Does your fnSplit() return a Sequence Number as well?  If so just add an Order By after your WHERE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your `inner join` is changing the order. Since you are only using it for filtering, you can change the `inner join` into a `where exists`. This should preserve the order:

```
INSERT INTO Favorites( username, id )
SELECT  @username, i.item
FROM fnSplit(@id, ',') i
WHERE EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1
   FROM dbo.Link f
   WHERE f.id = i.item AND f.id IS NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, removing the join solved that issue!

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
Declare @username varchar(50) = 'dynamic'
Declare @favorite varchar(50) = '19,1,10'

Insert Into Favorites (username,id) 
Select @username,f.ID
 From  [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@favorite,',') i
 Join  dbo.Link f on f.id = i.RetSeq
 Where f.ID is not null
 Order By RetSeq                  -- << Notice we added an Order By
```

**If it helps with the visualization:**

```
Select * From  [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('19,1,10',',')
```

**Returns**

```
RetSeq  RetVal
1       19
2       1
3       10
```

**The TVF which will supply a Sequence (RetSeq)**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Thanks Shnugo for making this XML safe
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('this,is,<test>,for,< & >',',')
--Performance On a 5,000 random sample -8K 77.8ms, -1M 79ms (+1.16), -- 91.66ms (+13.8)
```